# JQuery if value is in an array

Tags: jquery

i am trying to use this code:

```
        <?php
        $return_arr = array();
        $sql="SELECT * from customer where email <> '' group by email ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $return_arr[] = array('value' => $result["email"]);
        }
        $data = json_encode($return_arr);
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var email_array = <?php echo $data; ?>;

            $('#email').on('keyup',function(){
                if ($.inArray($(this).val(), email_array) !== -1) {
                    alert();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

to check if a value already exists when typing in a text box

my input is: `<input type="text" id="email" />`

when i type an email in that exists in the JQuery array its not showing an alert.

The value of the JQuery array is like:

```
var email_array = [{"value":"email@domain.co.uk"},{"value":"email@domain.com"}];
```

Comment: The above code should work fine. Post the rendered code of `email_array`

Comment: please check my update

Comment: this is the problem. You have to have an array of strings where as here you have array of object.

Comment: how do i make it an array of strings in the php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$return_arr[] = array('value' => $result["email"]);
```

with

```
$return_arr[] = $result["email"];
```

This will return array of strings instead of array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Change the code of the javascript function to:

```
if ($.inArray({"value":$(this).val()}, email_array) !== -1) {
        alert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this enter code `here` **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsal_Arsal/fr4vqv79/)** this will check character by character in any array. if it helps endorse please.